# An exercise related to the Baire category theorem

Tags: general-topology

I am looking for some hint for the exercise 2. Can anyone help me? I will appreciate any help. Thank you so much![image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do the second one for you

Let $X$ be a countable complete  metric space without isolated points.Then $X=\cup_{x\in X}\{x\}$.As $X$ has no isolated points so $\{x\}$ is nowhere dense and thus $X$ has been expressed as a countable union of Nowhere Dense sets thus making $X$ a set of 1st category contradiction to Baire  Category th.

Comment: What about the completeness of the space X? Should we use it to do this exercise?

Comment: Yes completeness is needed. A complete metric is of 2nd category according to th. got it

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: remove one point at a time.

Comment: How do you mean? Can you explain more for me :)

Comment: Consider sets consisting of all but one point of the space.